# How do i change channel permissions for everyone in DSharpPlus?

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

I want to create a /lock command that changes channel's send messages permission to false to @everyone

Python example that works:

```
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lock(ctx: SlashContext, channel):
    await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

My c# code:

```
[SlashCommand("lock", "")]
[SlashRequirePermissions(Permissions.ManageChannels)]
public async Task Lock(InteractionContext ctx, [Option("channel", "")] DiscordChannel channel)
    {
        // Change channel send messages permission to false for everyone
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried, code wise, in C#? Looks like an empty method.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is get the @everyone role, which according to the official discord API is the same as the Guild Id:

```
var lEveryoneRoleOfYourServer = await lYourDiescordBotClient.GetGuildAsync(aYourGuildId).GetRole(aYourGuildId);
```

Then you have to use DiscordOverwriteBuilder to build overwrite @everyone role permissions when you will create your channel.

```
var lYourOverWriteBuilderList= new DiscordOverwriteBuilder[] { new DiscordOverwriteBuilder(lEveryoneRoleOfYourServer).Deny(Permissions.SendMessages) };
    
var lNewChannel = await lGuild.CreateChannelAsync(aYourNewChannelName, aChannelType, lYourOverWriteBuilderList);
```

In case you would like to do it with already created channels as I think you want to do, then you use:

```
await lChannel.ModifyAsync(x => x.PermissionOverwrites = lYourOverWriteBuilderList);
```

But be careful because all permissions on this channel will be overridden so in case you want to keep them you have to add them to your new overrides "lYourOverWriteBuilderList". This can be a bit tricky so feel free to reply here in case you can't figure it out.